# How to include this code in a C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am running into problems with my Database not opening because it is already, apparently, open.

> Unable to copy file "j:...\KAELC_DB.mdf" to "bin\Debug\KAELC_DB.mdf".
>   The process cannot access the file 'j:...\KAELC_DB.mdf' because it is
>   being used by another process.
>
> Unable to copy file "j:...\KAELC_DB_log.ldf" to
>   "bin\Debug\KAELC_DB_log.ldf". The process cannot access the file
>   'j:...\KAELC_DB_log.ldf' because it is being used by another process.

I found a reply to an old question on StackExchange, linked to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998383, by "Justin", which looks to resolve that problem (and I have also read in other places that "using" is one of the most efficient ways of programming in C#) but how do I use this in my code ?

I have created a small Project that does nothing but allow me to press a button in order to process a SQL statement, but I'm confused as to what "Justin" means by "Use the connection" ... how do I put SQL statements into this code ?!?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MySqlTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open SQL File
            using (SqlConnection conn = SqlHelper.GetConn())
            {
                // Use the connection <<< How ?!?!?
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Insert Record Into  SQL File

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Read Record From SQL File

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Read All Records From SQL File

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Delete Record From DQL File
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Close SQL File
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Quit
            this.Close();
        }

        class SqlHelper
        {
            public static SqlConnection GetConn()
            {
                SqlConnection returnValue = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MEDESKTOP;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlTestDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=MySqlDB;Integrated Security=True");
                returnValue.Open();
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for any documentation on `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Justin's answer has nothing to do with your problem. I presume you are getting this error during a build, inside Visual Studio? It doesn't say there are problems *opening* the file, but rather copying it to your `bin\Debug` folder.

Comment: This might be coz, you have attached u r mdf file to the sql server database ,just deattach the file from the sql server and then place it in Debug folder

Comment: @Douglas - I have been using different sites, books & videos to try and learn C#, but there seem to be dozens of different ways of doing everything and everybody seems to think their way is the best !!! I have been advised to use one site / book & stick to it, so maybe I will do that, but it is so frustrating when I do that & find that there are easier / better ways somewhere else !!!

Comment: @Groo - yes, it is a debug run inside VS2010, but the problem is that (as far as I can ascertain) it can't copy it because it is already Open. If I restart my PC it works fine, so it is obviously something to do with the file being held / locked and Justin's code "insinuates" that this is avoidable ... but I need help finding out how !!!

Comment: @Smack - I'm not sure what you mean ... within the Project I create a new Database, it is for this Project alone, and nothing else. Yet sometimes I can access it, sometimes I can't, there is obviously something that is locking me out (and as I have said to Groo) if I reboot the PC I can access it again. I, surely, shouldn't have to worry about attaching & de-attaching my databases, is VS2010 not supposed to control all of this and make life easy(ish) for me ?!?

Comment: @Gary: there is nothing which will stop you from creating multiple connections to a database. It would be really ugly if you wanted to create a web site which allows only one user at a time. What Justin wanted to say in that question is, if you create a single connection inside your app, don't bother if it's connected or not, but rather create a new one every time you need it, and dispose it afterwards. However, the problem you are facing is happening before you even start your program - once you start your app, the file will already be inside your Debug folder and then there are no problems.

Comment: @Gary: additionally, why is this file even being copied to the Debug folder? Did you set a "Copy to output directory" option in VS? Because there is no need for the database file to be copied there on each build.

Comment: @Groo - I haven't changed any Options as far as I know, I've checked through Tools / Options and can't even see where I would do this, can you tell me where ?!?

Comment: @Groo - My C# book says "The other object that is automatically created when you drag a table to the screen is an instance of
SqlDataAdapter. The adapter classes are a new feature of the .NET data access scheme. In a nutshell, a data adapter automatically generates a local copy of a database on the client’s computer, and manages the relationship between the local copy of the database and the original database." ... could this be why a copy is taken into the Debug folder ?

Answer (score 1):

if all you want to do is run an SQL command, use an SQLCommand object. ([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx))

here is the sample code from the article...

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

things to note:

1. uses a `SqlConnection` object with a `Using` block
2. uses an `SqlCommand` object
3. uses an `SqlDataReader` object
4. explicitly closes the `SqlConnection` with finished with it

Comment: Why not put the `SqlDataReader` in a `using` block as well? Then there's no need to close it.

Comment: you can put the data reader in a using. its good practice to always close your connections (etc): two rules to live by: people are stupid, and trust no one

Comment: I don't actually understand your comment. As @DBM mentioned, these classes implement `IDisposable` (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader), and all of them should be put inside `using` blocks. Writing `try/finally` blocks is simply more work to do, less readable and more prone to an error (you forgot to dispose the `SqlCommand`, for example). What's any of that have to do with "people are stupid" or "trust no one"?